# iOS - appending text to a file in the application bundle

Tags: objective-c, ios, file, nsstring, append

I'm trying to append some text to a file that resides in the application bundle with the following code:

```
NSString *dotsStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", dots];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i_500", dots] ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];

NSString *newpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i_50", dots] ofType:@"txt"];
[contents appendToFile:newpath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

When appending to the file, I'm using a category on NSString:

```
- (BOOL) appendToFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc;
{
    BOOL result = YES;
    NSFileHandle *fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
    if (!fh)
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:nil attributes:nil];
        fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
    }
    if (!fh) return NO;
    @try {
        [fh seekToEndOfFile];
        [fh writeData:[self dataUsingEncoding:enc]];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e)
    {
        result = NO;
    }
    [fh closeFile];
    return result;
}
```

This is working fine on the simulator, however, when I restart the app, the old file gets loaded, without the appended text. I have no idea how this is possible.

Does anyone know how I could change this category so that the changes are persistent?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't write to the app bundle.

(For quite obvious security reasons, by the way.)

If you're intending to change a file, copy it to a writable location, for example in the Documents directory.

(Oh, and before you ask it: the simulator uses OS X's file system, where this restriction is not present, so that's why it works on the simulator. Another thing the simulator fails to simulate.)

Answer (score 2):

Application bundle is read-only. You need to copy your file to application's Documents directory before modifying it.